# How can I have dwm start with a different view (i.e., a different tag)?

Tags: window-manager, dwm, tiling-wm

`dwm` starts with with the first tag in view. How can I modify `dwm.c` or `config.h` in order to start on another tag?

Comment: This makes no sense; dwm's [tags are not workspaces](http://web.archive.org/web/20120120161931/http://lubutu.com/rant/dwm-faq), so where dwm "starts" is irrelevant. If you do want to mimic workspace behaviour, look at the [pertag patch](http://dwm.suckless.org/patches/pertag).

Comment: I had feared this would just descend into an argument about terminology.

I assign my web browser tag 1, and I don't want to change that because I've gotten too used to my keyboard commands. I want to continue to start the browser in my .xinitrc, I just don't want to see it when I first start dwm. Ideally I'd like to load with an initial view of a different tag (or tags), but for the browser to be on the same tag it always has been.

Comment: Try http://dwm.suckless.org/patches/emptyview

Comment: This works well enough for what I'm trying to do - cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late to the party, but another option would be to add an xdotool command to your startup.

xdotool key Shift+Alt+2